# Groovy (build.gradle) vs Kotlin (build.gradle.kts)

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, groovy

В чём могут быть преимцщества перехода с Groovy (build.gradle) на Kotlin (build.gradle.kts) в Андроид-проектах? Когда это имеет смысл?

Comment: Kotlin everywhere и все.

Comment: Объективный ответ дать нельзя, кому-то приятнее писать на котлин, потому что язык статически типизированный и лучше работают подсказки в IDE.

Comment: То есть какой-то принципиальной разницы (технической, например), кроме вкусовщины, нет? Кроме подсказок...

Comment: А что для вас важно для системы сборки? При переходе с Groovy на Kotlin может измениться скорость сборки. Как в лучшую, так и в худшую сторону. Kotlin, предположительно, компилируется при первом запуске долго. Поддерживать код на Kotlin проще и удобнее, сложнее допустить ошибку. В остальном, наверное, различий не так много)